# Phpunit, expect method(true) and method(false)

Tags: php, phpunit

I want to test this:

```
$object->method(true);
$object->method(false);
```

I want to test them like that:

```
$mock1 = $this->getMock ('ClassToBeTested', array('method'));
$mock1->expects ($this->at(1))->once()->method('method')->with($this->equalTo(false));
$mock1->expects ($this->at(2))->once()->method('method')->with($this->equalTo(true));
```

this of course doesnt work. I need a kind of "multiple" exception.

Comment: Can you not do it in separate tests, with the @expectedException?

Comment: ? I dont wait "exception". I wait method() run with "true" and "false" parameters

Comment: The at() is for calls, 1st call to the method, 2nd call, etc...  You could still test it simply calling the method with the mock, using 2 tests, and the setUp()/tearDown() methods to wrap the mock creation, and simply mock the calls.  $mock1->expects($this->method('method')->with($this0>equalTo(false/true));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need can be archieved by using `withConsecutive`.

Example adapted from the PHPUnit docs:

```
    $mock = $this->getMock('ClassToBeTested', array('method'));
    $mock->expects($this->exactly(2))
         ->method('method')
         ->withConsecutive(
             array(true),
             array(false)
         );

    $mock->method(true);        
    $mock->method(false);
```

Look at the `withConsecutive` example here:

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html